# Right Justified Text Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to have my lisp code output something that is right-justified. I looked up the documentation for format ([doc link](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cfb.htm)) and was trying the following

```lisp
(format t "~10:<*~>")
```

The problem is that running this code gives me this:

> ```
>      *         *
>      *
> ```

instead of giving me something like this:

> ```
>    **
>     *
> ```

Below is the whole function, though I don't think that it is the one causing any issues:

```lisp
(defun triangle-print-neg (rows numStar)
   (cond
      ((= rows 0) (return-from triangle-print-neg nil)) ;If rows = 0, force exit
      ((< numStar (abs rows)) (progn
           (format t "~10:<*~>")
           (triangle-print-neg rows (+ numStar 1)) ;Call function again but with numStar + 1
      )); numStar < abs(rows) print("*")
      (t (progn
             (format t "~%")
             (triangle-print-neg (+ rows 1) 0)
       )) ; Else call triangle print neg with row+1, 0
   )
)
```

Thank you

Comment: You asked format to left-pad one star to ten characters and print that. Which it's doing. Repeatedly. You may need to prepare your multiple stars for one line into one string and then pass them to format all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your underlying problem, which is to print a triangle, presumably as part of an exercise in learning Lisp, and that you are (I am guessing) not very familiar with Common Lisp, I would suggest *not* trying to understand the details of the language of `format` strings, which is hairy and entirely unrelated to Lisp except insofar as it happens to be embedded in CL, and instead simply write a function to do what you want using simple printing operations.

The two simple printing operations you need are:

- `princ` which prints something without any decoration like newlines or quotes;
- `terpri` which prints a newline.

Given these two operations you can write a procedure `princ-n-padded` which prints `n` copies of a character, padded to a given width, followed by a newline.  You can use the dirty trick of having the width be negative to indicate padding on the right.

Here is such a procedure:

```
(defun print-n-padded (c n width &optional (to *standard-output*))
  "Print a line with N copies of C in width |WIDTH|.
If WIDTH >= 0 then print left justified, if it is < 0 print right justified.
The optional TO argument is the stream to which to print."
  (if (>= width 0)
      (dotimes (i width)
        (princ (if (< i n) c #\Space) to))
     (dotimes (i (- width))
       (princ (if (< i (- (- width) n)) #\Space c) to)))
  (terpri to))
```

And now

```
> (dotimes (i 10)
    (print-n-padded #\* (+ i 1) -10))
         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
nil
```

As you can see this is straightforward code, with no hairy and hard to understand `format` strings.  In real life you might, eventually want to start using `format` in non-trivial ways, but very often it is simply easier to write code which does what you want, where what you want is something relatively simple, rather than write code which is full of line-noise strings.

---

If you are required to do this recursively then you can do that too:

```
(defun print-n-padded (c n width &optional (to *standard-output*))
  "Print a line with N copies of C in width |WIDTH|.
If WIDTH >= 0 then print left justified, if it is < 0 print right justified.
The optional TO argument is the stream to which to print."
  (if (>= width 0)
      (princ-ab c #\Space width (- width n) to)
    (princ-ab #\Space c (- width) n to))
  (terpri to))

(defun princ-ab (a b n m to)
  "print (with PRINC) a total of N copies of A or B, printing N-M of A
followed by M of B, to TO.  Do not print a newline"
  (cond  ((> n 0)
          (princ (if (<= n m) b a) to)
          (princ-ab a b (- n 1) m to))
         ((= n 0)
          nil)
         ((< n 0)
          (error "negative-creep"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun my-triangle (k)
   (format t "~10@a~&" (make-string k :initial-element #\a))
   (unless (zerop k)
     (my-triangle (decf k))))
MY-TRIANGLE

CL-USER> (MY-TRIANGLE 5)
     aaaaa
      aaaa
       aaa
        aa
         a
          
NIL
```

I use `~a` with a padding of 10 and the left-align `@` modifier: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#justifying-on-the-left-